# Saving to the database when the button in the view is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, http-post

There are 2 models. The user is logging into the system. I want a value from the current model to be added to the logged in user's table when he clicks the button in the Forum View. Ogrenci Model enters the system. When the button is clicked, I want ProjectName to be added to the BekleyenProje column in the Ogrenci Model. How can I do that?

Model 1:

```
public class Ogrenci
{
    public int OgrenciID { get; set; }
    public int OgrenciNumarasi { get; set; }
    public string Ad { get; set; }
    public string Soyad { get; set; }
    public string Bolum { get; set; }
    public short Sinif { get; set; }
    public string Yetenekler { get; set; }
    public string Sifre { get; set; }

    public string BekleyenProje { get; set; }
    public string OnaylananProje { get; set; }

    //FK
    public List<Proje> Projeler { get; set; }
}
```

Model 2:

```
public class Proje
{
    public int ProjeID { get; set; }
    public string ProjeAdi { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }
    public DateTime EklenmeTarihi { get; set; }

    //FK
    public int OgrenciID { get; set; }
    public Ogrenci Ogrenci { get; set; }
}
```

ForumController:

```
public class ForumController : Controller
{
    private OgrenciContext db = new OgrenciContext();

    // GET: Forum
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Include(o => o.Ogrenci) -- öğrenci bilgilerini dahil ediyoruz
        return View(db.Projeler.Include(o => o.Ogrenci).ToList());
    }
}
```

Forum Index View (The button I'm talking about is here):

```
@model IEnumerable<DonemProjesi.Models.Proje>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed cols-3 custom_table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Proje</th>
        <th scope="col">Etkileşimler</th>
        <th scope="col">Yayınlanma Tarihi</th>
        <th scope="col">Detay</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjeAdi)</div>
                <small><a href="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ogrenci.Ad)</a></small>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul class="activity_outer">
                    <li><strong>03</strong><span>Başvuranlar</span></li>
                    <li><strong>01</strong><span>Dahil olanlar</span></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="last_activity"><span class="time_ago">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EklenmeTarihi)</span></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="login-button">@Html.ActionLink("Proje Detayı", "Details", "Proje", new { id = item.ProjeID }, new { @class = "detayy" })</button>
                <button type="button" class="login-button"></button>        //BUTTON IS HERE
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Also, Controller for Login:

```
public class SecurityController : Controller
{
    OgrenciContext db = new OgrenciContext();
    // GET: Security
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Ogrenci ogrenci)
    {
        var kullanici = db.Ogrenciler.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.OgrenciNumarasi == ogrenci.OgrenciNumarasi && x.Sifre == ogrenci.Sifre);
        if (kullanici!=null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(kullanici.Ad, false);
            Session.Add("OgrenciID", kullanici.OgrenciID);      //kimlik doğrulamasu yapılan kullanıcının ID'si alınıyor
            return RedirectToAction("Details","Ogrenci", new {@id=kullanici.OgrenciID });
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Mesaj = "Geçersiz numara veya şifre girdiniz!";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use repository pattern, but a direct solution would be:

```
kullanici.BekleyenProje = Request["ProjectName"];
db.SaveChanges();
```

Also it depends on how many properties you want to pass. If it's only one, you can send it in the Request. Otherwise, you create a view model with the necessary members.

Make sure the button is submitting the form and ProjectName is a hidden field inside the form.